# Best local SVN solution for small company

Tags: svn

I am going to start using the source control in my company and I don't know which solution would be best. Team Foundation? Tortoise? Something different?

We have a VMware server connected to the local network / VPN. I can make a separate Windows Server 2008 / Linux machine to store the data.

We are using Visual Studio 2008 and VS 2010.

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) + Apache for http-access to repos ([VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) Server in case of Windows-core)

Comment: I would add AnkhSVN for tight integration into visual studio: http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: or VisualSVN - http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VStudio exclusively, TFS (Team Foundation Server) may make more sense. It includes a ticketing system and integrates well with testing and QA workflows + there are tons of integration scenarios and plugins available.